# Bootstrap columns not aligning correctly vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, border-box

I have a bunch of elements that I have floating next to each other, they are not in separate rows so they drop to the next line when necessary and hence if one of the elements is shorter than another than the element below it should come up higher than it's siblings, however this doesn't appear to be the case, all of the elements act as if they are in a wrapper row and all have the same height.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXLQWg

You can see the top middle element has a smaller height but the element below it won't come up closer to it and is positioned with the other elements.

**Example Code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="list row">
    <div class="holder col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="review">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan et sem ut pretium. Sed nisl mauris, scelerisque eget nulla in,
                varius semper risus. Cras mollis lacus lacus, ut iaculis leo dictum sed. Quisque porttitor metus et faucibus mollis. Etiam eget velit
                aliquam nisl mattis gravida vitae ac purus. Suspendisse vel magna et leo rutrum varius ut sit amet metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
                in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse odio nisi, convallis nec lacinia condimentum, rhoncus nec mi. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->
    <div class="holder col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="review">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan et sem ut pretium. Sed nisl mauris, scelerisque eget nulla in,
                varius semper risus. Cras mollis lacus lacus, ut iaculis leo dictum sed.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->
    <div class="holder col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="review">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan et sem ut pretium. Sed nisl mauris, scelerisque eget nulla in,
                varius semper risus. Cras mollis lacus lacus, ut iaculis leo dictum sed. Quisque porttitor metus et faucibus mollis. Etiam eget velit
                aliquam nisl mattis gravida vitae ac purus. Suspendisse vel magna et leo rutrum varius ut sit amet metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
                in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse odio nisi, convallis nec lacinia condimentum, rhoncus nec mi. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->                
    <div class="holder col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="review">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan et sem ut pretium. Sed nisl mauris, scelerisque eget nulla in,
                varius semper risus. Cras mollis lacus lacus, ut iaculis leo dictum sed. Quisque porttitor metus et faucibus mollis. Etiam eget velit
                aliquam nisl mattis gravida vitae ac purus. Suspendisse vel magna et leo rutrum varius ut sit amet metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
                in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse odio nisi, convallis nec lacinia condimentum, rhoncus nec mi. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->            
    <div class="holder col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="review">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan et sem ut pretium. Sed nisl mauris, scelerisque eget nulla in,
                varius semper risus. Cras mollis lacus lacus, ut iaculis leo dictum sed. Quisque porttitor metus et faucibus mollis. Etiam eget velit
                aliquam nisl mattis gravida vitae ac purus. Suspendisse vel magna et leo rutrum varius ut sit amet metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
                in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse odio nisi, convallis nec lacinia condimentum, rhoncus nec mi. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->            
    <div class="holder col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="review">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan et sem ut pretium. Sed nisl mauris, scelerisque eget nulla in,
                varius semper risus. Cras mollis lacus lacus, ut iaculis leo dictum sed. Quisque porttitor metus et faucibus mollis. Etiam eget velit
                aliquam nisl mattis gravida vitae ac purus. Suspendisse vel magna et leo rutrum varius ut sit amet metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
                in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse odio nisi, convallis nec lacinia condimentum, rhoncus nec mi. 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Holder Ends -->            
</div>
<!-- List Ends -->
</div>
<!-- Container Ends -->
```

CSS:

```
.list {
    margin-top: 43px;
}

.list .holder {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.list .review {
    position: relative;
    padding: 14px 20px 20px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e67e22;
}

.list .review p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

From my testing it appears it is related to the setting `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Is there anyway to fix this so the smaller elements align directly under the element above it when it is able to or do I have to set `box-sizing` to `content-box`?

Comment: Due to the `float: left` your layout has a behavior of rows and you want it as columns. To do so you'll need to wrap every item in a column in the same layer.

Comment: @elboletaire Not quite sure what you mean.